# How to remap the backslash and backtick keyboard buttons? Windows 11

Tags: keyboard, windows-11, keyboard-layout

I've recently installed Windows 11 and they layout of my keyboard has swapped.

Everything works as expected apart from the issue that the backtick <kbd>`</kbd>  and backslash <kbd>\</kbd> characters on my keyboard have swapped places.

I know I can write a script in Autohotkey and swap their places however I'm sure there must be a way to fix this natively without resorting to Auto Hotkey.

OS: Windows 11
Keyboard: Logitech MX Keys

- I've tried swapping the Keyboard layout from windows settings.
- I've tried pressing <kbd>ALTgr</kbd> + <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> on the keyboard to see if that changes it
- Since I use multiple languages, it affects the other languages as well

Any ideas how I can swap them without the use of external software? Surely this is some windows thing?

Comment: Try Auto HotKey for this.

Comment: I'm specifically asking not to use it as before it worked without it, something changed with the recent windows installation and swapped the keys, tried with the keyboard layout but that wasn't it.

Comment: Windows 11 continues to change things so you may need to use a 3rd party approach.

Comment: What you appear to have is an ANSI/ISO swap. American ANSI keyboards have no character key left of Z, so \ is left of 1. European ISO keyboards have an extra \ key left of Z, so the ` key goes left of 1 instead.

Comment: @Tetsujin I think you're hitting the nail on the head, but how would I remedy this or swap the keys? The thing is if I go to a website like: https://keyboard-test.space when I press my ``` \ ``` key it says <undefined> as it can't even register it because of the layout.

Comment: I honestly don't know on Windows. On Mac you can ask it to re-evaluate the keyboard. You could maybe re-word your question & title based on this new info, though, & see if any Windows experts can help.

Comment: I've just had this problem with my Logitech K810 illuminated bluetooth k/b under Linux. Which was already a hassle because the Mint 21.1 bluetooth manager doesn't work with the K810, so I'd had to [downgrade to previous bluetooth manager.](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=2332012&sid=b7d35493de9cf2b9829f02dd5a4fa6d6#p2332012) But **Alt Gr + Fn + (key to the right of left shift - i.e. the one which should be backslash)** worked fine for me, once I found it!

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use only software by Microsoft, you could use the
[Microsoft PowerToys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/).

The power toy to use is the
[Keyboard Manager utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/keyboard-manager) :

[image]

Comment: Although I like this better than running an autohotkey script, doing this configuration doesn't work as when I bind \ to ` and ` to \ pressing each key now produces \ instead of vice versa. I think this is due to the fact that I have 2 keys on my keyboard that are producing the backslash as @tetsujin pointed out in the comments because I have a European keyboard.

Comment: If PowerToys can't do it, then only Autohotkey is left.